# Thread-safety with int - easy

Tags: java

I think this code is thread-safe, but if I place the synchronized after the if, it's not thread-safe isn't it ? I have just a doubt :

```
public class decrementIfSup0 {

    private static int cpt = 5;

    public void decrement() {
        synchronized(cpt) {
            if(cpt > 0)
                cpt--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot synchronize on an int

Comment: Read the compiler error messages. When presenting code ensure that either 1. the code is valid or; 2. explain why it isn't valid (but shows the desired intent).

Comment: Why don't you use an `AtomicInteger`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I wanted to suggest it in my answer but the ``cpt > 0`` statement makes the atomic block mandatory anyway (without further tricks)

Comment: @JeanLogeart Not as of [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#updateAndGet-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-).

Answer (score 1):

The `cpt` variable needs to be `volatile` to prevent threads from caching its value:

```
private static volatile int cpt = 5;
```

And you also need to synchronize the method:

```
public synchronized void decrement() {
    if(cpt > 0)
        cpt--;
    }
}
```

Comment: `volatile` is not needed when (1) variable is final (2) variable is used only by one thread (3) *variable is used only inside synchronized blocks*

Comment: Not sure there is no getter here.

Comment: @user2864740 how can two threads get in if the method is synchronized?

Comment: @user2864740 What is ``synchronized`` for?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the entire method synchronized and static you are guaranteed to be thread safe.

public class decrementIfSup0 {

```
private static int cpt = 5;

public static synchronized void decrement() {
    if(cpt > 0)
        cpt--;
}
```

}

Be careful with this though, as it will be a bottleneck in your code as each thread
must wait for another to be completely done before it is allowed to execute. Depending
On how often this method is called it could slow down your code.